# Where are the "belongs on..." closing options?!?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons, close, belongs-on

I was trying to close [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/191817/non-system-disk-or-disk-error) as belonging on superuser.com, but I don't see anymore the "belongs on..." options when clicking the "close" button.

What happened to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths.

From what I can work out (since I don't see these options) you need to click **Off Topic** and the migrate options will be presented.